# nginx - deny all *.php requests except index.php for security reasons

Tags: nginx, php, security, configuration, drupal

os: CentOS 7
nginx: 1.6.2
httpd: apache 2.4.6
cms: Drupal 7

After my server was compromised I removed all from server, reinstalled OS and soft, and restored data from backup.
Now I configure all services in maximum security style.

After detail researching access logs - I decided **to deny any requests for php files except index.php** which is in the site documents root for improving security.

Nginx access log contents a lot of records like:

```
azenv2.php
az.php
```

and

```
/*/wp-login.php
/administrator/index.php
/MyAdmin/index.php
```

First category - backdoors (and one of them hacked my sites, somebody send huge portion of spam from my server).

Second - somebody want to find popular cms and utilities and try some login@password, like admin@123456

My reasons to block both categories by nginx through deny requests to php files are:

1. Even if somebody will upload php-shell - **it will be impossible to use it**.
2. All these requests are 'not good' a priory - and to refuse them by nginx will protect drupal(httpd+php+mysql) to work and spent power.

My current config for one virtual host:

```
server {

  listen <server-ip>;
  server_name <site-name>;

  location ~* /sites/default/files/styles/ {
    try_files $uri @imagestyles;
  }

  location @imagestyles {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|pdf|zip|rar|mp3|flv|doc|xls)$ {
    root <site-documents-root>;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ (^|/)\. {
    deny  all;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    access_log <path-to-log-folder>/nginx_access.log main;
  }

}
```

nginx.conf - was not changed after installation.

---

**UPDATE**
Finally I create this config for deny:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  access_log /path/to/log/nginx_deny.log name_log;
  deny all;
}
```

and this config for proxy:

```
location =/index.php {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location =/cron.php {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

1). So full information about attacks attempts is collects in log.
2). Server not make additional work for bad requests.
3). Drupal cron may work.

Comment: A probably superfluous question: have you read the canonical https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: I had read a lot of about security during last two weeks :) I have no problems with fact of compromised - all actions already done - new os, soft, complex clean sites files.
Now - I need to protect by maximum new server.
ssh, selinux, httpd, php seems secure. 
Strongly nginx configurations can improve security.

Comment: Anyone able to give me feedback on the following? While what OP is doing is not too logical, I'd like to know if this would do what he wants: location ~ \.php$ { deny all } location \index.php { proxy_pass whatever }

Comment: @Peter unfortunately that would result in the denial of the request to index.php also, as the `location ~\.php$ { deny all }` directive would also match `index.php`

Comment: What _exactly_ does `which is in the site documents root for improving security` mean? Where was it before? There's also no php handling at all in the above config - so not very clear.

Comment: AD7six, index.php always in the site root as by default. I want to refuse requests to use backdors (if they will appear in future) and deny spam traffic. I added some more information to the main description.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in a number of ways.

Integrating quite directly with what you have in your config file, you may wish to simply include a section such as the following;

```
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files index.php @error;

fastcgi_pass ...;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to$fastcgi_script_name;

...
}

location @error {
[config of however you want to handle errors]
}
```

Which will check for the existence of the requested file before allowing its access/execution.

Further to the above however, I would actually personally recommend using [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which will provide you more comprehensive security if configured correctly; you can configure it to monitor your access logs in real-time and ban IPs from accessing your server(s) by automatically creating new iptables rules on-the-fly, with ban times which you specify.

Personally I have my servers configured to use fail2ban with nginx as per [this article](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/554-how-to-secure-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban) (or at least based upon that - you may alter it as you wish).

Comment: fail2ban won't stop someone from exploiting a vulnerability in some web portal (like Drupal, for instance).

Comment: Of course not, but that is neither what was requested by OP nor what I detailed in my response. It is however a point worth noting - known vulnerabilities in packages should be tracked and software updated accordingly.

Comment: I try your advice and get <invalid number of arguments in "try_files"> after reload.

Comment: Alright, it would seem that `try_files` requires at least two arguments then - I would suggest that you set up a second argument to point to an error location if you wish (answer updated to reflect this change above)